# php resize image zoomcrop without border (logic)

Tags: php, resize, gd, zooming, crop

i have a image manipulation class, i want to create images that always fill the entire new width and height so there are no borders/solid color background, i just cant understand how i can make it always fill the height and width (**mantaining the aspect ratio of the uploaded image**) if the image width AND height are smaller than the new image size..

just like the zoomcrop (zc=1) from phpthumb class (i looked the code from it but i couldnt mimic the behavior)

```
    public function resizeCrop($newwidth, $newheight) {

                        ...

            $x = $this->getX();
            $y = $this->getY();

            ...

            else if ($x < $newwidth && $y < $newheight)
            {

            // logic ??

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the smaller (relative to the aspect ratio of the original image and that of container) side is zoomed to maximum. Have a look at this code:

```
public function resizeCrop($newwidth, $newheight) {
                ...
    $x = $this->getX();
    $y = $this->getY();

    // old images width will fit
    if(($x / $y) < ($newwidth/$newheight)){
        $scale = $newwidth/$x;
        $newX = 0;
        $newY = - ($scale * $y - $newheight) / 2;

    // else old image's height will fit
    }else{
        $scale = $newheight/$y;
        $newX = - ($scale * $x - $newwidth) / 2;
        $newY = 0;
    }

    // new image
    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

    // now use imagecopyresampled
    imagecopyresampled($dest, $src, $newX, $newY, 0, 0, $scale * $x, $scale * $y, $x, $y);
    return $dest;
}
```

**Update:** Corrected the function. It is now working perfectly, I have tested it on my dev  machine.

Comment: @l0l0l0l0l what exactly do you mean by does not scale like it should. A better description of the problem might help. Also is this a reproducible error, if so can you give a sample original width and height that produces incorrect scaling.

Answer (score 1):

To *maintain aspect ratio*, you need to choose: either make the image too big and then crop the original, or you make it fit just right and then fill in the parts that don't reach the edges with a solid color.

The former, you can compare the percentage change for width and height respectively, then use the larger percentage as a multiplier against both dimensions. For a 1 x 1 unit image that you want to fit into a 2w x 3h unit area and maintain aspect ratio: you can use a 3x multiplier, get a 3 x 3 unit image, and crop .5 units left/right.

The latter, you use the smaller percentage as a multiplier. For a 1 x 1 unit image that you want to fit into a 2w x 3h unit area and maintain aspect ratio: you can use a 2x multiplier, get a 2 x 2 unit image, and add .5 units of solid color top/bottom.